# Fail to use python with OneDrive for business to download a file shared with me

Tags: python, onedrive

While I can successfully list the files shared with me on OneDrive for Business, I am stuck with a python program trying to download any such file.

My OneDrive application has permission: `Files.ReadWriteAll`.
I can successfully **list** the files shared with me with the Python SDK and via the HTTP REST API.

For example, using the access token from a fully authorised OneDrive SDK `client` instance, I construct HTTP requests directly. This allows me to successfully list my shared files.

```
url = client.base_url + '/drive/oneDrive.sharedWithMe'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'bearer 
    {}'.format(client.auth_provider.access_token)})
```

(`base_url` is in the form `https://{org-name}-my.sharepoint.com//_api/v2.0/`)

The response content json provides me with a list of items and their remoteItems.

```
data = json.loads(response.content)

{'@odata.context': 'https://{myorg}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items',
 'value': [{'@odata.editLink': 'drive/items/1234',     
   'remoteItem': {'createdBy': {'user': {'displayName': 'name'}},    
    'id': '12345',    
    'lastModifiedDateTime': '2017-05-16T10:20:00Z',    
    'parentReference': {'driveId': '12345'},
```

However I fail to **download** any of these items when I insert the remote items into a `drives/{}/items{}` request

```
drive_id = data['value'][0]['remoteItem']['parentReference']['driveId']
remote_item = data['value'][0]['remoteItem']['id']
url = client.base_url + '/drives/{}/items/{}'.format(drive_id, remote_item)
response = requests.get(url, 
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(client.auth_provider.access_token)})
```

I always get a `404` `{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"The resource could not be found."}}`.

These are the response headers:

```
{
'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8',
 'Expires': 'Wed, 03 May 2017 09:42:27 GMT',
 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 18 May 2017 09:42:27 GMT',
 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
 'X-SharePointHealthScore': '0',
 'X-SP-SERVERSTATE': 'ReadOnly=0',
 'ODATA-VERSION': '4.0',
 'SPClientServiceRequestDuration': '173',
 'SPRequestDuration': '339',
 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319',
 'SPRequestGuid': 'cbd1f29d-707d-4000-e8b4-e8ef24e0143e',
 'request-id': 'another id',
 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000',
 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN',
 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET',
 'MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices': '16.0.0.6504',
 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
 'X-MS-InvokeApp': '1; RequireReadOnly',
 'P3P': 'CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"',
 'Date': 'Thu, 18 May 2017 09:42:26 GMT'
}
```

I am happy with any solution. It can use the OneDrive SDK directly or create HTTP requests by hand.

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For the files that you get the 404, are they also on the personal site host (https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com), or are they on the tenant site host (https://tenant.sharepoint.com)?

Comment: @Brad They are also on the personal site host: https://{my org}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my colleague's email/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=some id &file=my important.docx&action=default

Comment: Hmm, at a glance it seems you're going everything right. Can you update the question to include the headers you get back in the 404 response?

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but could you include the value for `SPRequestGuid`? It's a randomly generated GUID that the service creates to identify the request, and so cannot be used to identify your app / user / tenant. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908737(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Hi @Brad, I added the `SPRequestGuid` back in - does that help you?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner - it this case it really looked like the target file didn't exist. I'll assume that it really does exist, in which case my only other thought could be some kind of permission issue - can you try making the request with a token that represents the owner of the file?

Comment: @Brad I watched a colleague today creating a new Excel spreadsheet and sharing it with me. I can see it in the "Shared with Me" view of OneDrive. I have full permissions. Because I download my own files, it would be identical for him, to download a file that I shared. Any other ideas?